# Android SOLite Error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

> 01-22 21:43:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(30859): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-22 21:43:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(30859): Process:
>   com.it.heritageireland, PID: 30859 01-22 21:43:23.703:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30859): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.it.heritageireland/com.it.heritageireland.Favourites}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE products(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
>   AUTOINCREMENT ,productname TEXT, ) 01-22 21:43:23.703:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30859):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
>   01-22 21:43:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(30859):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)

I'm getting the above error when loading my android app on a S5 but it works fine on my Sony T.

Any ideas???

Thanks for looking.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // create statement for making the table - the table is called inventory
    String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS +"("+
            COLUMN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME +" TEXT " +
            ")";

    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

}
```

Comment: Not possible to answer without the relevant code.

Comment: you have the log with the complete sql query and where the error is. What else do you need?

Comment: I've added the sql code.

Comment: This is not the code that produces the stacktrace and adding a semicolon doesn't solve the problem in the stacktrace.

Comment: I added a semicolon and and it fixed the issue. What do you think is causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a semicolon after `)`. like `");";` at the last line.
complete query should be something like :

```
String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS +"("+
        COLUMN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
        COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME +" TEXT " +
        ");";
```

Comment: So simple. It had been annoying me for ages. Thanks, you're a legend. :-)